# Setinterval and Focus Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, setinterval

I am trying to detect if the browser window is in focus and to kill the ajax calls if it is not. Basically, if the user is idle for a certain amount of time, then the ajax kills will die, but will start again once the browser comes into focus. I think Facebook does it.

Here is what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        // window.onunload = function(){alert('closing')};

        // mainmode();

        $('#alertbox').click(function(){
                $('#alertbox').slideUp("slow");
        });


        setInterval(function(){

            // Check focal point
            var window_focus = true;

            $(function() {
               $(window).focus(function() {
                    window_focus = true;
                    console.log('Focus');
                });

                $(window).blur(function() {
                    window_focus = false;
                    console.log('Blur');
                });
            });


            if(window_focus == true){
                console.log('in focus');
                waitForMsg();
            }else{
                console.log('out of focus');
            }

        }, 5000);





    });
```

waitformsg is my ajax call. I just set a 5 second interval and it seems to be going crazy on my test browser. This probably isn't the best way to do it either.

It also seems to not be killing my ajax call, but instead multiplying it. Should I use xhr.abort()?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: you may want to look at requestAnimFrame instead.  Those are only executed when the browser is in focus.

Comment: @JustinThomas seems like more for animation than logical focus/blur operations.. If you think I can use this, could you post an answer?

Comment: It is, but there's nothing to say you couldn't use it for what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified code;

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // window.onunload = function(){alert('closing')};

    // mainmode();

    $('#alertbox').click(function(){
            $('#alertbox').slideUp("slow");
    });
    // Check focal point
    var window_focus = true;


           $(window).focus(function() {
                window_focus = true;
                console.log('Focus');
            });

            $(window).blur(function() {
                window_focus = false;
                console.log('Blur');
            });


    setInterval(function(){
        if(window_focus == true){
            console.log('in focus');
            waitForMsg();
        }else{
            console.log('out of focus');
        }

    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: This looks like it will work, except my ajax kill still runs.. There is a settimeout in there. Is there a way to kill any ajax calls running? xhr.abort?

Comment: I think you should stop sending request to server after window.blur. use xhr.abort if you really want abort your request(in case it take very large server resource).

Comment: I cant abort.. Check my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393465/kill-ajax-session-outside-of-originating-function