# Kill Ajax Session Outside of Originating Function

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, setinterval

I have an AJAX function I'd like to kill, but it is outside of the function. Take a look:

```
function waitForMsg(){

       var heartbeat = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "includes/push_events.php",
            tryCount : 0,
            retryLimit : 3,
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            // timeout: 500,

            success: function(data){ 
                console.log(data);
                if(data){
                    if(data.current_date_time){
                        updateTime(data.current_date_time);
                    }
                    if(data.color){
                        console.log("Receiving data");
                        displayAlert(data.color, data.notification_message, data.sound, data.title);
                    }
                    if(data.user_disabled){
                        console.log("Receiving data");
                        fastLogoff();
                        checkDisabled();
                    }       

                }
                setTimeout(
                    waitForMsg,
                    5000 
                );
            },


            error: function(data){
                if (data.status == 500) {
                    console.log("Connection Lost to Server (500)");
                        $.ajax(this);
                } else {
                    console.log("Unknown Error. (Reload)");
                        $.ajax(this);
                }

            },

            dataType: "json"

        });
    };

    // Detect browser open.


    $(document).ready(function(){

        // window.onunload = function(){alert('closing')};

        // mainmode();

        $('#alertbox').click(function(){
                $('#alertbox').slideUp("slow");
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){


    $('#alertbox').click(function(){
            $('#alertbox').slideUp("slow");
    });


    // Check focal point
    var window_focus = true;


           $(window).focus(function() {
                window_focus = true;
                console.log('Focus');
            });

            $(window).blur(function() {
                window_focus = false;
                console.log('Blur');
            });


    setInterval(function(){
        if(window_focus == true){
            console.log('in focus');
            waitForMsg();
        }else{
            console.log('out of focus');
            heartbeat.abort();
        }

    }, 5000);
});




    });
```

If you notice, the ajax is outside of the document.ready. I am trying to kill the ajax calls if the user goes to a different window, then restart the calls once the return to the window. The start works, but if the user goes away from the window, it gives me the "heartbeat is not defined". Obviously this is because its outside of that function. Any work arounds?

Comment: Get rid of the `var` keyword, and the variable will be a global variable.

Comment: @Barmar Tried this.. continues to run ajax.

Comment: What do you mean by "*... a different window...*"?

Comment: @Alexander If the user has a few tabs open and they navigate to a different tab for too long, I want to kill the ajax calls.. when the come back to my site, to reactivate ajax calls.

Comment: @greycode, fair enough

Comment: @Alexander I also don't think the setInterval is the best method either. It's just what I was working with and trying to get to work. I took Barmar's advice and made heartbeat global. Still doesn't seem to kill it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd refactor a bit the code to avoid the usage of `setInterval` and clean up a bit the code.

You can abstract the logic in an object, let's say `Request`. You can add two methods to `resume` and `stop` which will handle the status of the underlying AJAX request.

```
var Request = function(options){
    var request = this, xhr = null, aborted = false;

    /* Resumes the operation.
     * Starts a new request if there's none running.
     */
    request.resume = function() {
        aborted = false;
        request.retry();
    };

    /* Retry loop.
     */
    request.retry = function(){
        if(!xhr) {
            xhr = $.ajax(options).done(function(){
                request.destroy();
                !aborted && setTimeout(function(){
                    request.retry();
                }, options.timeout);
            });
        }
    };

    /* Aborts the current operation.
     */
    request.abort = function(){
        aborted = true;
        if(xhr) xhr.abort();
        request.destroy();
    };

    /* Destroy.
     */
    request.destroy = function(){
        xhr = null;
    };

    return request;
};
```

Now, you can drop the `setInterval`.

```
$(function () {
    var request = new Request({
        type: "GET",
        url: "includes/push_events.php",
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data){ 
            /* Success handler */
        },
        error: function(data){
            /* Error handler */
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });

    $(window).focus(function () {
        request.resume();
    }).blur(function () {
        request.abort();
    });

    request.resume();
});
```

The `Request` constructor receives the `$.ajax` options which should contain an additional `timeout` parameter that specifies the delay between requests.

Comment: Alexander, looks pretty formidable! Could you take it a tiny step further link up your code and mine? AJAX is still sort of new to me and the code you wrote above seems a little confusing. I'd appreciate it if you could.

Comment: Maybe I'm old fashioned but `request = undefined;` looks all wrong. I know it works, but `request = null;` or `request = false;` seem so much more logical. All are falsy so the test can be `if(request) ...`

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot can you make an answer?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot, granted. I prefer to use `null` though

Comment: @Alexander This works great, much easier to work with looks like. The only thing is the "blur ajax killer" part doesn't work. Looks to still be running.

Comment: @greycode, it will run at most once. Since, I suppose at some point it is impossible to abort it though

Comment: @Alexander Actually i take that back. It finishs the call then stops. Great! Would this be considered long polling or just standard?

Comment: This is not long polling. This is just a simple retry loop

Comment: @Alexander Also, if you reference my code in the beginning where I log  console.log("Unknown Error. (Reload)");, it keeps hitting that with your code implemented. Any ideas?

Comment: @greycode, I tested it and it should be working. Be sure to remove all the custom code you put to retry a request

Comment: @Alexander Okay cool. For what you can see here, would you recommend we move to comet or something else?

Comment: @Alexander, there's a good reason for my answer (now deleted) being totally irrelevant - I got confused between tabs and posted in the wrong place; doh! doh! doh!

Comment: @greycode, I can't tell. I am not aware of your requirements. Let me know if this answer worked for you or not

Comment: @Alexander Works! It basically is checking for messages from MySQL. It is delivered via push_events.php. I just don't want it to overload the server checking every few seconds with a thousand users.

Comment: Please look at my my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422850/detect-mousemovent-inside-of-blur-function-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop further request after window.blur. restart request after window.focus.

Modified code

```
var setTimeoutConst;
function waitForMsg(){
        if(!window_focus){
             return; //this will stop further ajax request
        }
       var heartbeat = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "includes/push_events.php",
            tryCount : 0,
            retryLimit : 3,
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            // timeout: 500,

            success: function(data){ 
                console.log(data);
                if(data){
                    if(data.current_date_time){
                        updateTime(data.current_date_time);
                    }
                    if(data.color){
                        console.log("Receiving data");
                        displayAlert(data.color, data.notification_message, data.sound, data.title);
                    }
                    if(data.user_disabled){
                        console.log("Receiving data");
                        fastLogoff();
                        checkDisabled();
                    }       

                }
                setTimeoutConst= setTimeout(waitForMsg,5000);
            },
            error: function(data){
                if (data.status == 500) {
                    console.log("Connection Lost to Server (500)");
                       // $.ajax(this);
                } else {
                    console.log("Unknown Error. (Reload)");
                        //$.ajax(this);
                }
                setTimeoutConst= setTimeout(waitForMsg,5000); // continue sending request event if last request fail
            },
            dataType: "json"

        });
    };

var window_focus = true;
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#alertbox').click(function(){
        $('#alertbox').slideUp("slow");
    });

    $('#alertbox').click(function(){
            $('#alertbox').slideUp("slow");
    });
    // Check focal point
     $(window).focus(function() {
        if(window_focus ){return}
        window_focus = true;
        waitForMsg(); 
        console.log('Focus');
    });
   $(window).blur(function() {
          if(!window_focus ){return}
        clearTimeout(setTimeoutConst);
        window_focus = false;
        console.log('Blur');
    });

    waitForMsg();            
});
```

Comment: Looks like this works! I removed the waitforMsg(); under window.focus so it's not calling twice :)

Comment: If the user clicks elsewhere, then back into the site, it starts to call ajax twice. If they do it again, it will add another ajax call of the waitforMsg();

Comment: yes you are right so onblur you need to clear settimeout. added cleartimeout

Comment: Okay, that kills the additions, but a single click away then click back calls waitformsg() twice.

Comment: No it will get called only from inside window focus method

Comment: Look beneath .blur. I am testing right now. It is calling twice after the first blur to focus event.

Comment: I am using waitForMsg beneath blur to call it first time . As window.focus would not fire. After page load only window.focus will call waitForMsg

Comment: Haha I am telling you man, it is firing twice for some reason.

Comment: .focus and .blur fire twice for some reason it looks like.

Comment: I was debugging your code and found that you ate using .ajax(this). Which is creating lots of request removing those lines will solve your problems . By the way why are using them

Comment: I use .ajax(this) when the request fails, it restarts it. It should not be interfering with your proposed option.

Comment: I am able to produce the bug (focus and blur firing twice). but dont know reason . I solved using flag.

Comment: Please look at my my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422850/detect-mousemovent-inside-of-blur-function-jquery