# Detect Mousemovent inside of blur function Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, mousemove

I am trying to create a neat way to stop an AJAX called based upon if the browser is in focus, and if the mouse moves.. So here's what I want it to do:

If the user goes to a different tab in their browser, minimized the window, or goes somewhere else other than the web app, I want it to kill the AJAX calls in 1 minute. If the user moves the mouse anywhere in the web app, it should consider the user "focused" on the app, and thus continue the ajax calls. I put a timeout called "st" in there to take care of the "timeout" portion, but adding in a mouse detector is a little more advanced. Here's what I have:

```
var window_focus = true;
$(document).ready(function () {    

    $('#alertbox').click(function () {
        $('#alertbox').slideUp("slow");
    });

    // Check focal point
    $(window).focus(function () {
        if (window_focus) {
            return
        }
        window_focus = true;
        waitForMsg();

    }).blur(function () {
        if (!window_focus) {
            return
        }
        console.log('Init Suspension...');
        // Set Timeout
        $(function () {
            st = setTimeout(function () {
                clearTimeout(setTimeoutConst);
                window_focus = false;
                document.title = 'Timed Out | WEBSITE';
                console.log('Suspended');
            }, 60000);    
        });
    });

    waitForMsg();
});
```

I was going to try adding in something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $().mousemove(function () {
        console.log('Reinitialize');
        clearTimeout(st);
        waitForMsg();
    });
});
```

But it didn't work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: have you tried  `$(document).mousemove`? Are you going to cancel that mousemove the first time it happens or just go crazy?

Comment: @popnoodles I have not tried that. I want to cancel the "st" timeout timer and continue pulling ajax calls like normal. If it detects mouse movement, I basically want it to go back to thinking it's in focus.

Comment: @popnoodles Basically it won't think it's in focus again until I go to a different window, then go back to that one. I want to simply think it's in focus if it detects the mouse moving.. Get it?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/popnoodles/5mqMm/

You probably want this using `.one()`. This will see the mouse move, run your procedure and not run it again, until the window is reloaded or it's on another page.

Putting it inside of blur means blurring sets it up again.

```
}).blur(function () {
    $(document).one('mousemove', function(){
       // i react ONCE to the mouse being moved
         console.log('Reinitialize');
         clearTimeout(st);
         waitForMsg();
         // focus the window again as desired
         $(window).trigger('focus');
    });
    if (!window_focus) {
        return
    }
    console.log('Init Suspension...');
    // Set Timeout
    $(function () {
        st = setTimeout(function () {
            clearTimeout(setTimeoutConst);
            window_focus = false;
            document.title = 'Timed Out | WEBSITE';
            console.log('Suspended');
        }, 60000);    
    });
});
```

Comment: Can I build this into my .blur function though? basically force it to think it's in focus?

Comment: `$(window).trigger('focus');` should do it but I've never triggered that on window before.

Comment: Okay looks like that works, yet if the user navigates away, it won't re-blur it. I'll add my code to your answer.

Comment: Oh I see what's happening. Works great when the user runs their mouse into the window and its out of focus.. What what if the user leaves the window again. It will never quit the calls. Should I do a mouseleave?

Comment: Test if leaving the window triggers mouseleave in a jsfiddle. You might need window blur for that. But you have a blur, surely that is triggered when the user leaves the window?

Comment: Gotcha. I think I figured this out. I want to use "on" instead of one, in case the user does it multiple times while out of focus. Is there a way to get out of the "on" loop? I want it to jump back up to the (window).focus function

Comment: Right got you. Of course it only happens once without reloading. Ok, if you use `.on()` you'll run that procedure many many times in quick succession (example http://jsfiddle.net/popnoodles/5mqMm/1/ ) so you need to think your way out of that

Comment: Where did you put that? There's an end bracket on .blur and I don't have anywhere I can place that

Comment: I've shown you in the updated code.  Here's an example. Watch the 4th number. Click on the bottom right pane to focus and one of the others to blue. http://jsfiddle.net/popnoodles/5mqMm/3/

Comment: This is what I have.. Sort of working, but not clearing timeout. http://jsfiddle.net/CBsqd/

Comment: `$(this).blur(function () {` inside `$(window).blur(function () {` is unnecessary. Will you drop some HTML in there so I can see what's going on?

Comment: There is no HTML to go with it haha. It's just killing the ajax calls.  Standard html, body, etc. Here's the gist. If the user is focused on the window, continue calling waitforMsg();. If they user is on a different window or minimized and it's not detecting mouse activity, kill the ajax calls. If the window is considered "blurred" (out of focus) but the window sees mouse activity, consider it in focus. As soon as the mouse leaves, out of focus again. I don't ever want it to get to the mouse part if it's back in focus.

Comment: That's the biggest problem I was having. Once the window is out of focus, then back into focus, it would continue to honor the mouseenter/mouseleave and I don't want it to do that. If the window is in focus, continue the ajax calls, no matter if the mouse is on the window or not.

Comment: Ok. You can see your errors in the console. http://jsfiddle.net/popnoodles/CBsqd/1/

Comment: I didn't include waitformsg() in the fiddle, its not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GpjGY/)

```
var window_focus = true, lastMouseMoveTime;
$(document).ready(function () {    
    lastMouseMoveTime = new Date().getTime();
    $('#alertbox').click(function () {
        $('#alertbox').slideUp("slow");
    });

    // Check focal point
    $(window).focus(function () {
        if (window_focus) {
            return
        }
        window_focus = true;
        waitForMsg();

    }).blur(function () {
        if (!window_focus) {
            return
        }
        window_focus = false;
        console.log('Init Suspension...');
        // Set Timeout
    });

    waitForMsg();
    $(document).mousemove(function(){
        lastMouseMoveTime = new Date().getTime();
        if(!window_focus ){
            waitForMsg(); // restarting ajax if it stopped because of mousemove.
        }

    });

});
```

in your ajax call method

```
if( !window_focus){
     if( new Date().getTime() - lastMouseMoveTime   > 60*1000 ){
            return;
     }
}
```

Comment: This is great! You are the best! Few things: 1: Should I copy my st timer into your comment area? If I move the mouse back into the window, it doesn't start the ajax calls again. See my long comments in the previous answer about how I want it to happen. Thanks @Sushil!

Comment: If the window is out of focus, but it detects the mouse moving, then I want it to continue to make ajax calls for another 6000ms.

Comment: You cant get mousemove event on blured window

Comment: I fixed issue of restarting ajax.

Comment: ohh I was not aware of that. but I believe my previous change will solve this problem as well

Comment: Nope.. logged "init suspension" moves mouse into window, doesn't restart ajax.

Comment: There was a problem in if (last )condition. it is working now check fiddler link.

Comment: Okay that works!!! Now.. When the window is considered in focus, and I move the mouse outside of the window, it will stop the ajax. If the window is in focus, I don't want it to ever care about mouse position.

Comment: use && instead of || in last if

Comment: With && it will ignore the blur mousein-mouseout thing you just fixed.

Comment: Changes in fiddle or answer?

Comment: changes are only in Answer

Comment: Out of focus never kills the calls now.